# How do I get more dwellers to automatically come to my Vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

There were a few dwellers that came to my Vault when I started the game a few days ago. But after that no more dwellers have come, even though I have lots of space for them to join in and work. Obtaining more dwellers via babies is not working well, so I need walk in dwellers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have 20 dwellers living in your vault, you can build a radio station. This will attract people from the outlands to you.

Comment: Just a note.  The sheer time radio station needs to work is really huge.  Two 10 Cha with +5 armor takes approximately 4 hours per dweller.  The percentages are abysmal.  If you are having problems growing babies, the radio tower is usually not a valid solution.  It might be better to fix your baby problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to complete objectives by getting enough caps to earn lunch boxes — or you can buy them — which sometimes contain cards that award a new dweller with nice skills and equipment.

Answer (score 1):

radio station not working for me ... I'm baby making all the way 
just make sure your not trying to mate family as this don't work
.... just try upgrading a 3 wide living quarters and filling it with both sex they will pair up and start the process :)

Answer (score 0):

there is also another way but it works only few times. close fallout shelter and open it again . you may see a dweller coming to your vault. this can only work if you wait atleast 1 minute.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this works? It sounds like a random occurrence wrongly interpreted as cause and effect.